# How to play and detect an object using captured video in background subtractor model?

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, image-processing

everyone.! I am using opencv2.4.2. actually I am doing project on object  detection. I tried using BackgroundSubtractorMOG model.
           But I am not able to load video file from my computer. While running on real time this below code for segmentation works fine.
           I have implemented using frame differencing method for object detection. Now I want to segment whole object from the background. I have static background. so can anybody help me in below code how to segment object from captured video. also how to load a video file?
           thank you.

- ```
        #include "stdafx.h"
        #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
         #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
         #include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"
         #include "conio.h"

        #include "time.h"
        #include "opencv/cvaux.hpp"
        #include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
        #include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"

        using namespace std;
        using namespace cv;
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
   {
  //IplImage* tmp_frame;
  //std::string arg = argv[1];
  //VideoCapture capture();
        cv::VideoCapture cap;

         /*CvCapture *cap =cvCaptureFromFile("S:\\offline object detection                 database\\SINGLE PERSON Database\\video4.avi");
        if(!cap){
          printf("Capture failure\n");
           return -1;
          }

          IplImage* frame=0;
          frame = cvQueryFrame(cap);           
           if(!frame)
  return -1;*/



       bool update_bg_model = true;

      if( argc < 2 )
      cap.open(0);
      else
      cap.open(std::string(argv[1]));

      if( !cap.isOpened() )
     {
      printf("can not open camera or video file\n");
      return -1;
     }

      Mat tmp_frame, bgmask;

      cap >> tmp_frame;
      if(!tmp_frame.data)
      {


      printf("can not read data from the video source\n");
      return -1;
      }

       namedWindow("video", 1);
      namedWindow("segmented", 1);

      BackgroundSubtractorMOG bgsubtractor;

      for(;;)
     {
      //double t = (double)cvGetTickCount();
      cap >> tmp_frame;
      if( !tmp_frame.data )
          break;
      bgsubtractor(tmp_frame, bgmask, update_bg_model ? -1 : 0);
      //t = (double)cvGetTickCount() - t;
      //printf( "%d. %.1f\n", fr, t/(cvGetTickFrequency()*1000.) );
      imshow("video", tmp_frame);
      imshow("segmented", bgmask);
      char keycode = waitKey(30);
      if( keycode == 27 ) break;
      if( keycode == ' ' )
          update_bg_model = !update_bg_model;
       }

        return 0;
       }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video loading in opencv works for me. To load a video you can try something like this. Once you have captured frame you either do processing in the loop or can call a separate function.

```
std::cout<<"Video File "<<argv[1]<<std::endl;

cv::VideoCapture input_video(argv[1]);

namedWindow("My_Win",1);

Mat cap_img;

while(input_video.grab())
{
   if(input_video.retrieve(cap_img))
   {
     imshow("My_Win", cap_img);
     /* Once you have the image do all the processing here */
     /* Or Call your image processing function */
     waitKey(1);

   }
}
```

or You can do something

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{

    char *my_file = "C:\\vid_an2\\desp_me.avi";
    std::cout<<"Video File "<<my_file<<std::endl;
    cv::VideoCapture input_video;

    if(input_video.open(my_file))
    {
         std::cout<<"Video file open "<<std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"Not able to Video file open "<<std::endl;

    }
    namedWindow("My_Win",1);
    namedWindow("Segemented", 1);
    Mat cap_img;
    for(;;)
    {
         input_video >> cap_img;
         imshow("My_Win", cap_img);
          waitKey(0);
    }
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: hi..Thank you for the reply. but actually its not opening a video file.also as you can see in my code:for(;;)
   {
    //double t = (double)cvGetTickCount();
    cap >> tmp_frame;// it gives error in ">>" this line.don't know why. using MAt definition is there any other way for playing a video? or is there any mistake?please guide me. thank you.

Comment: The above code is working for me, I'm able to load video and play it. It think you should check the file name which you are loading. Is it the correct file. Also on windows you will need to use \\ instead of \. e.g const char *my_file = "C:\\My_Folder\\my_file.mpg": something like this

Comment: I tried you code too but not everything just file open part and frame read. It is working for me, I feel you take a look at the file name which you are passing. As I said on windows you need to use double slash "\\" as folder separator.

Comment: hi..:@praks411; I run the above code.it work fine for laptop camera.means for real time application.but as you said I tried using const char also but its giving error in: cap >> tmp_frame;and shutting down application.don't know how to load?

Comment: You can refer my new edited code, if you are able to open file successfully then it should work. The above code works for me on visual studio 2010 OpenCV2_4_3