# Display JPEG Video Using cvShowImage

Tags: opencv

I need to display a video movie in jpeg format using `cvShowImage`. I read each of the frames into a byte buffer using:

> CVD::BasicImage FrameBytes = imageFromFile(Filename);

Next, I want to display the frame using:

> cvShowImage(WinName,frame);

However, cvShowImage accepts frames in `IplImage` or `cvMat` format. How do I send over the raw bytes to cvShowImage?

Comment: if you are trying to read frame from video file. I recommend to use video capture provided in OpenCV. You can also refer this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185456/how-to-play-and-detect-an-object-using-captured-video-in-background-subtractor-m/16186105#16186105

Answer (score 0):

If you have raw buffer alongwith image size(width, height) then you can use following for getting IplImage.

```
IplImage *m_img_show;
uchar *m_pBuffer;
CvSize cv_img_size = cvSize(m_width, m_height);
m_img_show = cvCreateImageHeader(cv_img_size, IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
cvSetData(m_img_show, m_pBuffer,m_width*3);
```

m_width and m_height are width and height of frame. 
m_pBuffer is raw image data.